# Is there a jQuery slideshow plugin that allows me to set the timing for individual images?

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I would like to know if there is a prebuilt slideshow for jQuery that will allow me to set longer a longer pause on some images than others.

I have bracketed photos and would like to fade through from the dark one to the medium exposed on. I think it will look groovy.

Cheers,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling `setInverval` on a function with two `setTimeout` calls inside it.

```
function doubleSlide() {
    setTimeout("switchSlide()",500);
    setTimeout("switchSlide()",2000);
}

setInterval("doubleSlide()", 2000);
```

The result is one slide displaying for 500 milliseconds and the next displaying for 1500 milliseconds.